# How to make Entity Framework 7 not use OUTPUT in updates?

Tags: entity-framework-core, sql-server-2017

I get this error when I update through EF 7: "The target table 'Table' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if
the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause."

EF 7 executes this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [ObrazacZahtjevZaIzvanrednuPozajmicu] SET [OdbijenOdobren] = @p0
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [ObrazacZahtjevZaIzvanrednuPozajmicuId] = @p1 AND [Zakljucan] = @p2;
',N'@p1 int,@p0 bit,@p2 bit',@p1=21858,@p0=1,@p2=0
```

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No example code is needed, any update would cause this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell EF that the table has a trigger. So in the `OnModelCreating` in your context, you use something like this:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<TableWithTrigger>()
    .ToTable(t => t.HasTrigger("NameOfTrigger"));
```

For info, this was documented in [Breaking changes in EF Core 7.0 (EF7)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#sql-server-tables-with-triggers-or-certain-computed-columns-now-require-special-ef-core-configuration)